# cd_storage_config path confusion?

Tags: 2009

Playing with cd_storage_config file and want to use a new folder on same machine and same drive to store website files when published. currently all files are published to "XYZ" folder and now should be published to "XYZ1" folder

I can see 3 cd_storage_config file in my current environment

1. cd_storage_config under bin/config of my web web site ("XYZ") folder, I don't think I need this folder here any more because once I publish a page, cd_storage_config of CD server will be used, I just removed this folder, did a server restart and things are working. Do I still need config files in my web site?
2. cd_storage_config under bin/config of CD server, I have changed storage path to "XYZ1"
3. cd_storage_config under bin/config of program files, which is currently pointing to "XYZ2" (folder just for testing)

I restarted all services and did IIS reset, When I publish I noticed as expected, "XYZ1" folder has been created on file system with my published files on the path which is defined in CD serer config file.

I did a system restart and publish some more files and noticed this time "XYZ2" has been create, that means it is taking config file under program files into account and if a publish again file will be publish to "XYZ1" folder which is fine.

Why file path defined in config file under program files is being used?
Do I need config files in my web site folder?

Comment: The cd_storage in your website bin/config is used for resolving Component Links (with the Linking API) and also for doing Broker queries.  If you remove that config file you might experience issues on your website

Comment: Are  your CMS & CD on same server? if yes CacheChannelService or any CD side service(if installed) might be accessing cd_storage_config under bin/config of program files.

Comment: yes all 3 items (CMS, CD and my web site) are on 1 server.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your publication target is pointing to a URL (check inside the cms) this URL is your deployer, which is a website that contains the application to deploy your files.  This website will contain a cd_storage_conf file which is used to determine where the published files will live.

Tridion is very modular in that the CME, Deployer and Website application typically can exist on different servers, which is why the deployer is built to function as a website.  So the storage configuration file that you're looking for may exist on a different machine to the location you're looking for and changing files, this is why you might not be seeing changes when editing files based on a search for the conf file by name on a particular server.

Ensure you're changing the right files and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as you said files can live on a completely different server, what does that mean? If CD server in on server 1 and can I change the path in config file to use IP/name of server 2 and copy files? or CD server must be configured on server 2 first and then in CMS as a new publishing target? Can i use remote machine's shared folder to publish my files or CD server only copy files to local machine where it is configured?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it clearer :)